# how to return Array values in yii2?

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

My view code is:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ReportSelection[]')->dropdownlist(['1' => 'Channel1', '2' => 'channel2','3'=>'channel3','4'=>'channel4'],['multiple'=>'multiple']); ?>
```

My controller code is:

```
return $this->redirect(['selectedreport','fromdate'=>$model->FromDate,'todate' => $model->ToDate,'reportselection' =>$model->ReportSelection,'reportoptions' => $model->ReportOption]);
```

My action function is:

```
public function actionSelectedreport($reportoptions,$reportselection,$fromdate,$todate)
```

I need `$reportselection` as argument here to use in:

```
foreach($reportselection as $i)   
{
    $selectlist = $selectlist . 'Channel'.$i.'Value,';
}
```

Comment: Please explain better. Your question i absolutely unclear

Comment: reportselection[] is unable to use ? how to return array ? how to pass array as argument in a function?

Comment: Your form field is inside a form? Do you want to pass the form value to the relative action? Please explain better

Comment: yes ofcourse need value to be passed to the action

Comment: in your action you can get your form data using Yii::$app->request->post() [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests)

Answer (score 0):

All action arguments are scalars by default. If you need accept array, you should explicitly specify this type in method signature:

```
public function actionSelectedreport($reportoptions, array $reportselection, $fromdate, $todate)
```